# Statistical test with file uploaded by user

Tags: r, file-upload, shiny, shinyapps, statistical-test

I am currently trying to develop an app that could realise statistical tests on any file uploaded by the user. The problem is that I often encounter problems trying to do the tests and many "error" messages appears. Here I cannot make the t-test work for example.
Would you kindly care to look for the errors in my code please, as I cannot seem to find them myself. Moreover, if you by any chance have any other codes to suggest that could resemble the app I am trying to create I would gladly like to see them to get some inspiration and better understand how Shiny works.
Here is the beginning of my code,
Thank you so much for your attention.

````
library(ggplot2)
library(desctable)
ui <- fluidPage(
  tabPanel(
    "Upload File",
    titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File', min=0 , max=1000 , value=500
                  accept=c('.csv')),
        checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
        radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                     choices = c(Comma=',', Semicolon=';', Tab='\t'),
                     selected = ','),
        
        selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', "", selected = NULL),
        selectInput('ycol', 'Y Variable', "", selected = NULL),
        selectInput("method", "Select t test type", 
                    c("One-sample t test",
                      "Independent two-sample t test"
                    ),
                    
        ),
        mainPanel(
         
          plotOutput('MyPlot'),
          tableOutput("table"),
          verbatimTextOutput("summary")
        )
      )
    )
  )
  
  server <- function(input, output, session)
  {
    output$table<- renderDataTable(input$file1)
    
    myfiles <- reactive({
      req(input$file1$datapath, file.exists(input$file1$datapath))
      
read.csv(input$file1$datapath)
    })
output$summary<-renderPrint(myfiles%>%desctable(stars=list((“N”  =length,
       “Moyenne”= is.normal~mean,
“Médiane”=median,
“MAD”=mad))    
  observeEvent(myfiles(), {
      req(myfiles())
      nms <- colnames(myfiles())
      updateSelectInput(
        session, 
        inputId = 'xcol', 
        label = 'X Variable',
        choices = nms, selected = nms[1]
      )
      
      updateSelectInput(
        session, 
        inputId = 'ycol', 
        label = 'Y Variable',
        choices = nms, selected = nms[1]
      )
    })
    
    output$table <- renderTable({
      if(is.null(dff())){return ()}
      
      if(input$method == "One-sample t test"){
        t.test(myfiles[input$xcol], mu = as.numeric(input$mu))
        
       else if (input$method == "Independent two-sample t test"){
        t.test(input$xcol ~ input$ycol, data = myfiles)}
        
        output$MyPlot <- renderPlot({
          req(myfiles(), input$xcol, input$ycol)
          ggplot(data = myfiles(), mapping = aes_string(input$xcol, input$ycol)) +
            geom_point() +theme_dark()
           
        })}
      
      
      shinyApp(ui , server)```
````

Comment: `output$table` is used twice (need to be unique), may need `req()` in the first one, and where is `dff()` object defined?

Comment: Welcome to SO, HanaeLevy! If you have errors, please don't make us guess at them or make us run things just to find your errors, please just [edit] your question and add the literal text of the errors/warnings (in a code-block). Also, as @YBS suggested, it appears that your code may be incomplete.

Comment: Thank your for your post. Would be nice to have the file and see how the app behaves in the first hand. Can you share the file or create a pseudoreplicate?